# Prisma query is not executing OR statement properly

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, associations, prisma

I need a query that only picks up Posts that are in a Space with PUBLIC in their types or where the userId is a member in the Space in which the post is made. For some reason this query gives me all post regardless of what is in Space Types or membership. It is like the OR statement does not exist at all.

Here is my query:

```
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
        where: {
            space: {
                OR: [
                    {
                        members: {
                            some: {
                                userId,
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        types: {
                            has: "PUBLIC",
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    });
```

Here is my schema:

```
model Post {
    id                     String                      @id @default(uuid())
    user                   User                        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    userId                 Int
    space                  Space?                      @relation(fields: [spaceId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    spaceId                Int?
}

model Space {
    id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
    members      SpaceMember[]
    types        SpaceType[]   @default([PUBLIC])
}

model SpaceMember {
    createdAt      DateTime           @default(now())
    user           User               @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    userId         Int
    space          Space              @relation(fields: [spaceId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    spaceId        Int

    @@id([userId, spaceId])
}

enum SpaceType {
    PUBLIC //defaults to PUBLIC, lack of PUBLIC means it is PRIVATE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. This code was giving undefined to the userId when not logged in. Apparently undefined brings back all results. I changed undefined to 0 and since there is no userId 0 then it does not bring up anything as a result.

```
    const userId = typeof userIdFilter === 'number' ? userIdFilter : undefined;
```

This is what made it work:

```
    const userId = typeof userIdFilter === 'number' ? userIdFilter : 0;
```